# Array Intersect in the same order PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5");
$array2 = array("7","2","3","1","5");
```

What I want to do is match the values in `$array1` and `$array2` strictly in order.

The desired output should be 2, 3 and 5 since 1 is not in the same order. I've tried `array_intersect` but it only matches array values and not taking account their order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have used a loop and then inside compare the values between the arrays 1:1. But there's the built in way in answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_intersect_assoc` as below:

```
$result = array_intersect_assoc($array1 , $array2 );
```